# Regex issue with php negative look behind for slash

Tags: php, regex

I always get this error when using a valid lookbehind with slash

> **Warning**:  preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: missing ) at
>   offset 22 in **[...][...]** on line **6**

Which is weird because on phplive regex it works perfect http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iiM but not on php 7 localhost

code is

```
<?php

$str = '[dzspgb_element text="<p><iframe src=\"https:/www.facebook.com/plugins/th=\"250\" height=\"500\" none=\"\" " kill_tinymce="on" type_element="text"][/dzspgb_element]';


preg_match_all("/(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\)(\")/sm", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

You can test it here - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Any idea what is wrong ? Maybe php 7 changed something in regex assertion ?

Comment: The error you got is `missing )` You have `(\w*?)` and `(?<!\)(\")` but in the middle there you have a new opening of `(`

Comment: sorry - the code is (\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\\)(\") - it got pasted wrong - and it makes no difference still missing ) even though there are no rogue )

LE: Seems that you need triple quote to print double quote in stack overflow comments

Comment: do you really need to `$$str` ?

Comment: nope - it got pasted wrong - but that is not the issue - fixed now

Comment: You could always use something else as opening and closing character like: `preg_match_all('~(\w*?)="(.*?)(?<!\)(")~sm', $str, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

You have:

```
(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\)(\")
```

The correct is:

```
(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!)(\")
```

pay attention: `(?<!\)` That slash is escaping the `)` so it isn't being understood as a `)`

EDIT:
I've learned that PHP needs some attention on escaping backslashes inside a string, see the Notes on top of this manual page: http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

So, to correctly escape your slashes, your code, with single quotes should be:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)(\")/sm', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: hey - thanks for the answer but  - the code is /(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\\)(\")/sm - recheck the first comment - so the ) should not be escaped really

Comment: oh sorry, try this instead: `/(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\ )(\")/sm`

Comment: yes it works but that is not the expected result - I need to escape the \ character not the SPACE character - would have been the same result as with /(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(\")/sm - check expected result here - http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iiM

Comment: i tried with the updated one - but not expected result - expected result is here - http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iiM

Comment: try: `/(\w*?)=\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)(\")/sm`

Comment: its really odd, its all because of a regex inside a php string. see the Note on this manual page: http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php